# Django runserver custom database

Tags: django

I'm using Django 1.4

I need to start the development server and I want to specify (in the command) which database it must use. For example if my settings contains:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'db.db',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
    },
    'tests': {
        'NAME': 'tests.db',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
    },
}
```

I want to use something like:

```
django-admin.py runserver --database=tests
```

There is something similar? I also tried to use a second setting file but the --settings option doesn't work: (--settings option seems to be deprecated, in [DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port) there is no mention at all)

```
django-admin.py runserver --settings=settings_tests
```

or

```
django-admin.py runserver --settings settings_tests
```

raises an error:

> ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings_tests' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings_tests

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I discovered that the right command to call in Django 1.4 is:

```
django-admin.py runserver --settings=myproject.settings_tests
```

Where is this information in the Django DOCS?

Thanks for all your response

Griffosx

Answer (score 35):

A cleaner and more scalable way to switch configurations than to create several config files would be to use environment variables (see [#3 of the twelve-factor app methodology](http://www.12factor.net/config) used by Heroku and others). For example:

```
from os import environ

DATABASES = {
    'main': {
        'NAME': 'db.db',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
    },
    'tests': {
        'NAME': 'tests.db',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
    },
}

default_database = environ.get('DJANGO_DATABASE', 'main')
DATABASES['default'] = DATABASES[default_database]
```

You can then change the default database by setting the `DJANGO_DATABASE` environment variable.

```
export DJANGO_DATABASE='tests'
./manage.py runserver
```

...or...

```
DJANGO_DATABASE='tests' ./manage.py runserver
```

You could also set environment variables using Python code.

---

Edit: To make this process easier, Kenneth Reitz has written a nice little app called [dj-database-url](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url).

Comment: Interesting, but I prefer to use the --settings option. Thanks

Comment: This solution helped me to keep same settings.py file for production and development, with database for production being chosen by setting an environment variable outside the application. Awesome!

Answer (score 7):

@Danilo Barges put a simple way to solve the problem. I only add a few change to deal with running tests. That's because `DATABASES['default'] = DATABASES[default_database]` will add an entry to `DATABASES` dictionary. So if you run tests the test runner will run against `'default'` and the next entry in `DATABASES`. Use two dictionaries instead:

```
DATABASES_AVAILABLE = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'db.db',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
    },
    'tests': {
        'NAME': 'tests.db',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
    },
}

database = os.environ.get('DJANGO_DATABASE', 'main')
DATABASES = {
    'default': DATABASES_AVAILABLE[database]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Create `settings_tests.py` with following:

```
from settings import *

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'tests.db',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
    },

}
```

Execute `django-admin.py runserver --settings=settings_tests`

Comment: It doesn't work. I already tried this solution but it raises the exception above. I am using Django 1.4

Comment: how can you get exception "no module" it you just created that module?

Comment: Well, actually the error is `ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings_tests' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings`. I already added the file settings_test.py in the root project directory (at the same level of settings.py). The error is about a _module_ not about a _file_...

Comment: A *file* **is** a *module*. The problem is that your `settings_test.py` file could not import the `settings` module. Do you have a `settings.py` file next to your `settings_tests.py` file?

Comment: Django 1.4 changed the default directory structure. The `settings.py` file is now in a subfolder, not on the same level as `manage.py`. In that case, use `from myapp.settings import *` instead of `from settings import *` (`myapp` corresponds to the name of that folder of course).

Comment: You are right, file is a module... anywhere, Django 1.4 changed the structure of a project, for this reason I though that --settings doesn't work. I discover instead that I have to call the command  `django-admin.py runserver --settings=myproject.settings_tests`